# How to use earlier declared variables within aes in ggplot with special operators (..count.., etc.)

Tags: r, ggplot2, scope

Let's say I want to plot histogram with the following formula (I know it's not the best but it will illustrate the problem):

```
set.seed(1)
dframe <- data.frame(val=rnorm(50))
p <- ggplot(dframe, aes(x=val, y=..count..))
p + geom_bar()
```

It works just fine. However let's say that we want for some reason frequencies divided by an earler defined number. My shot would be:

```
k <- 5
p <- ggplot(dframe, aes(x=val, y=..count../k))
p + geom_bar()
```

However I get this annoying error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'k' not found
```

Does there exist a way for using both `..count..`-like variables with some predefined ones?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems that there is some bug with `ggplot()` function when you use some `stat` for plotting (for example `y=..count..`). Function `ggplot()` has already `environment` variable and so it can use variable defined outside this function.

For example this will work because `k` is used only to change `x` variable:

```
k<-5
ggplot(dframe,aes(val/k,y=..count..))+geom_bar()
```

This will give an error because `k` is used to change `y` that is calculated with stat `y=..count..`

```
k<-5
ggplot(dframe,aes(val,y=..count../k))+geom_bar()
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'k' not found
```

To solve this problem you can kefine `k` inside the `aes()`.

```
k <- 5
ggplot(dframe,aes(val,k=k,y=..count../k))+geom_bar()
```

Comment: @DidzisElferts That would have never occured to me. I was ready to post an answer using `get`.

Comment: @kuba `p <- ggplot(dframe, aes(x=val, y=..count../get("k", envir=.GlobalEnv)))`

Comment: I think there's a bug to be honest; ggplot() has an `environment` parameter, but it seems to be ignored when stat variables are used

Comment: @baptiste It seems so because code ggplot(dframe,aes(val/k,val))+geom_point() works without problems

Comment: @DidzisElferts one sometimes finds problems with scope when ggplot() is called within a function, but usually using environment works. Here it doesn't.

Comment: This is brilliant. This is either a bug or just poorly documented (surprising because I generally find ggplot documentation superb). Either way, excellent to know.