# Passing variable to cut() in ggplot2's aes()

Tags: r, ggplot2, cut

I'm trying to use ggplot2 to draw a histogram that has different colour-bars for different intervals of x.

After referring to Hadley's solution in: [how to define fill colours in ggplot histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546016/how-to-define-fill-colours-in-ggplot-histogram), I arrived at the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
a <- seq(from=1, to=10000)
b <- rnorm(10000)
c <- data.frame(a,b) # Convert to DF

ggplot(c, aes(x=b, fill=cut(..x.., breaks=c(-2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2)))) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1, color="steelblue")
```

However, when I try to define the break points into a variable, MyBreaks, to be passed into aes(), I get an error: "Error in cut.default(x, breaks = MyBreaks) : object 'MyBreaks' not found."

My code that generated the error:

```
MyBreaks <- c(-2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2)
ggplot(c, aes(x=b, fill=cut(..x.., breaks=MyBreaks))) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1, color="steelblue")
```

I did some research on similar errors encountered by other users, but the solutions did not seem to work for me.

For instance, the solution in [How to use earlier declared variables within aes in ggplot with special operators (..count.., etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832608/how-to-use-earlier-declared-variables-within-aes-in-ggplot-with-special-operator) gave: "Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:MyBreaks". My code is:

```
ggplot(c, aes(x=b, MyBreaks1=MyBreaks, fill=cut(..x.., breaks=MyBreaks1))) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1, color="steelblue")
```

I then tried the solution in [Local Variables Within aes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659133/local-variables-within-aes) but this gave the same: "Error in cut.default(x, breaks = MyBreaks) : object 'MyBreaks' not found". My code is:

```
.e <- environment()
ggplot(c, aes(x=b, fill=cut(..x.., breaks=MyBreaks)), environment = .e) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1, color="steelblue")
```

I have done basic programming before but R's learning curve is real steep! Would appreciate if someone can help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from Roland's comment here [How to use earlier declared variables within aes in ggplot with special operators (..count.., etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17832608/how-to-use-earlier-declared-variables-within-aes-in-ggplot-with-special-operator).

```
ggplot(c, aes(x=b, fill=cut(..x.., breaks=get("MyBreaks", envir=.GlobalEnv)))) +
geom_histogram(binwidth=0.1, color="steelblue")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Jake! This works, but can you explain why the selected solution in that case doesn't work for me? If it's too onerous, please include a URL and I will go read.

Comment: @NoviceProg I can't really give you any more information than the error message. Arguments passed to `aes` have to be length 1 or the same length as the data. In the link `k` is just a single number so it's of length 1. You could dig around the `ggplot2` source code to figure out why there's the length restriction

Comment: No problem, @Jake, you've been a great help already! I just started on R for a month and am already overwhelmed by its complexity. At this point, 'why' is secondary to 'how' and 'what'. Let's see if there are other solutions along the way. Thanks again!